# Planning for a file indexing program

Tags: c++, database

I'm somewhat new to C++, but not programming in general. I want to write my first practice program in C++ as a file indexing program.

It's seems easy enough scanning directories for names, storing that information, and filtering them depending on what I want to view.

What I'm concerned about is at some point, I want to index a whole drive (I have an extra 1TB drive apart from my OS to store files on). I have about 400,000-500,000 files on there and I was wondering what would be the best way to store this information? I highly doubt keeping all those records in a text file is optimal and would like to think it's naive.

Is there anything else I should be concerned about?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of queries are you planning to do?

Comment: Search for filenames and file types. Maybe later down the road I could add other types of filters such as filesize, date etc.

Comment: Get into Hash functions.

Comment: @Nav I'm guessing you're suggesting to store a hash value for every file on my hard drive? Please be more specific as to what you mean.

Comment: Yes. Using a hash function, you'll be able to search (very fast) for filenames and even strings within the files in the same way that Google Desktop does. This is a topic that I've only read about but not implemented, so a Google search will be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't some kind of database the obvious answer?

If you don't want to hook up to a server, you can try something like SQLite. Alternatively, if you only need to do basic lookups, you could also create your own proprietary file format. You can utilize any combination of binary and textual data in your file. It's hard to suggest possible layouts without knowing what data you need to store and how you'll be accessing it.

Comment: I would store filenames and filesize for now. After searching for a particular filename, I would like to make a basic console program to return the location of anything that matches. Does that help answer what I would be storing and how I would be accessing it?

Comment: Location of anything that matches what? The filename? If you don't want to use a database, just dump the info into a file. You need some kind of index where data being search is stored sorted and in a way that is quick and easy to extract. For example, have it at stored contiguously as an easy-to-get location in your data file.

Comment: To answer your first question: Yes, I would return the location that matches the filename. I didn't say I didn't want to use a database, though I do have a question. How would the database work? Would I have to connect to a server to be able to store/retrieve data or what? (Excuse my lack of knowledge of desktop applications, I come from a very web-oriented programming experience)

Comment: +1 for sqlite. As soon as you talk about this sort of data, its going to be useful to perform operations on it using SQL semantics, without having to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Tek: As I described in my answer, SQLite can be used when you DON'T want to connect to a database. Google SQLite for full details. SQLite could be overkill depending on your needs, which I know very little about.

Answer (score 0):

You can safely persist your data to a text file. However, you'd need to read the file into memory at startup, and do all the complex operations in memory. Even if we'd assume a naive approach, where you store the file path with every file, you'd still look at ~100 bytes/file, or ~50 megabyte. A smarter approach stores just the filename and a pointer to the directory name.